# Function for DataFrame operation using variables in the list with Python

Tags: python, function, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a list `list = ['OUT', 'IN']`where all the elements of the list is a variable name in the data frame with suffixes `_3M, _6M, _9M, 15M`attached to it.

List:

`list = ['OUT', 'IN']`

Input_df:

`ID OUT_3M  OUT_6M  OUT_9M  OUT_15M  IN_3M  IN_6M   IN_9M   IN_15M
A   2        3        4        6        2     3       4       6
B   3        3        5        7        3     3       5       7
C   2        3        6        6        2     3       6       6
D   3        3        7        7        3     3       7       7`

The problem I am solving to do is subtracting the

1.`OUT_6M` from `OUT_3M` and entering in into separate column as `Out_3M-6M`

2.`OUT_9M` from `OUT_6M` and entering in into separate column as `Out_6M-9M`

3.`OUT_15M` from `OUT_9M` and entering in into separate column as `Out_9M-15M`

The Same repeats to each and every element in the list while keeping the `OUT_3M` and `IN_3M` which I mentioned in the sample `Output_df` dataset.

Output_df:

`ID  Out_3M  Out_3M-6M Out_6M-9M Out_9M-15M IN_3M IN_3M-6M IN_6M-9M  IN_9M-15M
A   2         1         1           2        2      1        1         2
B   3         0         2           2        3      0        2         2
C   2         1         3           0        2      1        3         0
D   3         0         4           0        3      0        4         0`

There are many elements in the list which I need to perform operation on. Is there any way I could solve this by writing a function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by writing a function, aren't a couple of for cycles enough for what you want to do? Something like:

```
postfixes = ['3M','6M','9M','15M']
prefixes = ['IN','OUT']

# Allocate the space, while also copying _3M
output_df = input_df.copy()

# Rename a few
output_df.rename(columns={'_'.join((prefix, postfixes[i])): '_'.join((prefix, postfixes[i-1] + '-' + postfixes[i]))
                          for prefix in prefixes for i in range(1, len(postfixes))}, inplace=True)


# Compute the differences
for prefix in prefixes:
    for i in range(1,len(postfixes)):
        postfix = postfixes[i] + '-' + postfixes[i-1]
        output_df['_'.join((prefix, postfix))] = input_df['_'.join((prefix, postfixes[i-1]))].values - input_df['_'.join((prefix, postfixes[i]))].values
```

The output_df is a copy of input_df in the beginning, both to avoid dealing with the _3M case separately, and to pre-allocate the DataFrame instead of creating the columns one at a time (it doesn't matter in your code, but if you had thousands of columns it would waste time moving stuff around in memory otherwise...)

Also, you should avoid calling a list "list" or you're going to get some nasty-to-find bugs along the way when you're trying to convert a tuple to a list!