# Operations on two lists with in a DataFrame using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, logic

I have two lists `ListA = [In_3M,Out_3M, Go_3M]` and `ListB = [In_6M,Out_6M, Go_6M]`. The elements in the two list are the variables of `Input DF`. I want to subtract the first element of "list B" i.e, `In_6M` with first element of "list A" i.e,  `In_3M` in the `Input DF` and it store it as a separate variable in the `Output df`.Then repeat the similar process until the end of the list and store in `Output df`.

```
ListA = [In_3M,Out_3M, Go_3M]

ListB = [In_6M,Out_6M, Go_6M]
```

Input df:

```
ID  In_3M   Out_3M  Go_3M   In_6M   Out_6M  Go_6M
 A   2        3       4       4        6      6
 B   3        3       5       5        6      7
 C   2        3       6       4        6      8
 D   3        3       7       5        6      9
```

Output df:

```
ID  In_3M   Out_3M  Go_3M   In_6M   Out_6M  Go_6M   IN_3M-6M    Out_3M-6M   Go_3M-6M
A     2       3       4       4       6       6       2              3        2
B     3       3       5       5       6       7       2              3        2
C     2       3       6       4       6       8       2              3        2
D     3       3       7       5       6       9       2              3        2
```

I have tried many ways to do this but cannot able to solve this. The number of elements in the list are around 20. Please help me if there any efficient way to do this. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Piinthesky Thanks for the observation and you are right! I did change the output.

Comment: @Zhoe sorry what is the difference with your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753808/function-for-dataframe-operation-using-variables-in-the-list-with-python ? It appears to me that the output is virtually the same as in the other case, at most with a pd.concat((input_df, output_df), axis=1) afterwards...

Comment: @MarcoSpinaci You are right! I was trying to solve the problem in other way which got me into this. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple enough to do with loops, just loop over the zipped column names:

```
>>> df = pd.read_clipboard()
>>> df
  ID  In_3M  Out_3M  Go_3M  In_6M  Out_6M  Go_6M
0  A      2       3      4      4       6      6
1  B      3       3      5      5       6      7
2  C      2       3      6      4       6      8
3  D      3       3      7      5       6      9
>>> ListA = ['In_3M','Out_3M', 'Go_3M']
>>> ListB = ['In_6M','Out_6M', 'Go_6M']
>>> for b, a in zip(ListB, ListA):
...     newcol = "{}-{}".format(b, a)
...     df[newcol] = df[b] - df[a]
...
>>> df
  ID  In_3M  Out_3M  Go_3M  In_6M  Out_6M  Go_6M  In_6M-In_3M  Out_6M-Out_3M  \
0  A      2       3      4      4       6      6            2              3
1  B      3       3      5      5       6      7            2              3
2  C      2       3      6      4       6      8            2              3
3  D      3       3      7      5       6      9            2              3

   Go_6M-Go_3M
0            2
1            2
2            2
3            2
```